# The structure of my loop depends on the step (python)

Tags: python, loops

I am given a list that contains both lists and integers inside it that looks like this:

`[4, [1], [5, [-2, 10], [1, -7] ], 6, [-2, [1, [0]], [9] ], [-3], [7, 3] ]`

I don't know the list or its structure off-hand. What I do is apply a function to the terms of the list that contain more than one term, i.e. `[5, [-2, 10], [1, -7]]`, `[-2, [1, [0]], [9]]` and `[7, 3]` in this case. In the next step of the loop, I want to apply the same function to these types of terms inside the last terms, i.e. to `[-2, 10]` and `[1, -7]` in the first case and to `[1, [0]]` in the second case.

For each step of the process, I have created a loop. The First step looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(var)):
    A,B=funct(var[i])
    aux.append(B)
    var[num[0][i]]=A
```

The second step looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(var)):
    A,B=funct(var[i])
    aux.append(B)
    var[num[0][i][0]][num[0][i][1]]=A
```

The third step is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(var)):
    A,B=funct(var[i])
    aux.append(B)
    var[num[0][i][0]][num[0][i][1]][num[0][i][2]]=A
```

I am only adding a `[num[0][i][j]]` to the `var` variable in each step.

Because I don't know the structure of the initial list I am given, I should write many `for` loops, each for each step of the process (whose quantity I don't know), but this is a waste of code. To solve that, is there a way to create a `while` loop that "appends" a piece of code like `[num[0][i][j]]` to the `var` variable at each step?

Edit: the `num` variable keeps track of the position of the lists with more than one term in the list. In the first step `num` is `[2, 4, 6]`. In the second step `num` is [[2, 1], [2, 2], [4, 2]]. This is why I need to add this extra `[num[0][i][j]]` each step.

Comment: I think you need to write recursive function and use `isinstance(e, list)` to separate `int`s from `list`s

Comment: What is `num`, what is `aux`? Perhaps if you had an example of `funct()` and the final values of `var`, `num`, and `aux` it would be easier to see what you at looking to do.

Comment: @YuriiMotov that part is not the problem here

Comment: @JonSG `var` is the list of the terms that contain more than one term at each step. `[5, [-2, 10], [1, -7]], [-2, [1, [0]], [9]], [7, 3]` in the first step. `num` is keeping the positions of the terms in `var` in the original list, it should be `[2,4,6]` in the first step. In the second it should be `[2,1]`, `[2,2]` and `[4,2]` i.e. the positions of the subterms in the original list. This is why each step needs and additional `num[0][i][j]` appended, because the list of terms in `num` has a new term each step. Hope that helps

Comment: If I understood your task correctly, you can use BFS algorithm. Where is an implementation with deque. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: I will explore that deque function, thanks. Yes, it is a BFS-type algorithm what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate through the levels of your structure with the following algorithm (BFS):

```
from collections import deque

lst = [4, [1], [5, [-2, 10], [1, -7] ], 6, [-2, [1, [0]], [9] ], [-3], [7, 3] ]


q = deque()
q.append(lst)

level = 0
while q:
    for i in range(len(q)):
        e = q.popleft()
        for e2 in e:
            if isinstance(e2, list) and (len(e2) > 1):
                q.append(e2)
                print(level, e2) # Do what you need
    level += 1
    print()
```

Output:

```
0 [5, [-2, 10], [1, -7]]
0 [-2, [1, [0]], [9]]
0 [7, 3]

1 [-2, 10]
1 [1, -7]
1 [1, [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is one function where we handle int and list separately. The computation can then automatically be applied recursively.

```py
def demo_plus_2(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x+2 # this part can be some function
    else:
        return [demo_plus_2(i) for i in x]
data = [4, [1], [5, [-2, 10], [1, -7] ], 6, [-2, [1, [0]], [9] ], [-3], [7, 3] ]
print(demo_plus_2(data))
```

outputs

```
[6, [3], [7, [0, 12], [3, -5]], 8, [0, [3, [2]], [11]], [-1], [9, 5]]
```